# Replying to people in social media without sounding insulting

Tags: conversations, etiquette, social-media, netiquette

### Background

I am watching professional wrestling. In the show I am watching, the commentary team is doing a good job, but lacking in one very important area. This particular area is not something that many fans need, I need it because I have a physical challenge and it would really help me if they improve on this area.

Two months ago, I found one of the commentator's twitter account. I quickly created my own account and tweeted him to make him aware of this particular area that they are lacking. It seemed to be received very well because they mentioned my tweet on the show.

However, though they've improved their commentating, they still are lacking at this particular area of commentating. I do not dare to tweet again because they might find it insulting.

### Problem

Yesterday, this commentator posted again. He asks for suggestions to improve his commentary. I cannot resist and sent him a reply that looks like this.

> Enjoyed what you did. My only suggestion is for the team. I am so thankful that you now ... more often since my tweet. Please do them more. Something as simple as ... would really really help a lot. Thanks!

Now, hours after replying, I began to feel that my actions might be inappropriate due to the following:

- They might feel I am demanding too much.
- There must be some reason why they didn't implement my suggestion earlier and I am disturbing them.

### My questions are:

- Is my message appropriate? Is there a chance this might be taken negatively?
- What should I have done?

Comment: Hi, as our [help/on-topic] says, we can't tell you what's right or wrong (and we also don't do phrasing requests). There is always a chance someone will take what you say negatively, so instead "focus your question on resolving your issue, rather than whether there is an issue or not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the excerpt you included here, it seems you are keeping a respectful tone and focusing on providing constructive feedback, exactly what they asked for.

Keep in mind that if this commentator has a particularly busy schedule or large audience they may lack the time to address specific repeat comments or are likely to get a very large number of messages, not all of which may be as respectfully phrased or helpful. The fact that they acknowledged your suggestion previously is a good sign, commentating something live it may take some time for them to remember your suggestion to be able to include it more often, give them time and know that you've done your part to try and help them deliver a better commentary.

As for why they might not have included your suggestion earlier, well common knowledge can be surprisingly uncommon sometimes :P